# Wix Installer showing 0x80070001: Failed while caching

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, code-signing, wix3.5

I am creating the Desktop application exe installer using Wix application. First I am creating MSI using Wix and then I am creating the exe installer using WixBootstrapper project. created exe installer is working good. But when I am getting issue when installing the exe after applied the EV code signing (using Yubikey USB device) using signtool from the command mode.

I am using the below command for code signing.

```
.\signtool.exe sign /fd sha256 /tr http://ts.ssl.com /td sha256 /a "E:\Prd5-56-3-4.exe"
```

Above command executes and got successfully signed message and can able to see the digital signature on the exe file. But issue is coming when installing the exe file.

Below shows the error I am getting when installing the exe file after code signing.

```
Failed to open container: WixAttachedContainer.
[3298:3008][2023-09-15T18:04:52]e312: Failed to extract payloads from container: WixAttachedContainer to working path: C:\Users\roshil\AppData\Local\Temp\{3DD6455A-2130-4F03-9AA7-2315C3BA9077}\ECDB0ABAF5AF393FFD526254943B2729C3DC92ED, error: 0x80070001.
[3298:4F68][2023-09-15T18:04:52]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[4928:1160][2023-09-15T18:04:52]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{cb5bf051-f7a1-4dc6-ad66-889e94f68984}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[4928:1160][2023-09-15T18:04:52]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {cb5bf051-f7a1-4dc6-ad66-889e94f68984}
[4928:1160][2023-09-15T18:04:52]i352: Removing cached bundle: {cb5bf051-f7a1-4dc6-ad66-889e94f68984}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{cb5bf051-f7a1-4dc6-ad66-889e94f68984}\
[4928:1160][2023-09-15T18:04:52]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{cb5bf051-f7a1-4dc6-ad66-889e94f68984}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[3298:4F68][2023-09-15T18:04:52]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070001, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```